# How do you know if it is morning or evening if I write 9 o'clock?

Tags: fiction

If I write 9 o'clock in my novel - or any o'clock - how does the reader know if that's morning or evening?

Comment: From the context, of course!

Comment: How often do the reader really need to know the precise time? I agree with the other answers, but this would be a better question if you gave more information on why you're asking and why you're discussing the time.

Answer (score 4):

How do you know if a speaker refers to a time in the morning or in the afternoon in the real world? Either by context, or you don't. And if you don't, you can ask.

Same in a novel or short story. If your character asks, "Do you want to have dinner at seven or eight?" you know it is in the evening. If your character is getting up for work and sees that it is already nine o'clock, you know it is in the morning. And if your characters wake up after a long night of heavy drinking and one of them says that it is already nine o'clock, the other can ask, holding his throbbing head: "A.m. or p.m.?"

Answer (score 3):

You don't, unless there's some external context.  You could say 9 o'clock in the morning, or evening or you could say A.M. or P.M. Except, if your writing fiction it might be smarter to do some showing rather than telling, usually the context will help with this. Did someone just get up? Did someone eat breakfast? Is it dark out? A little clue like that will usually do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this is great opportunity for you to add some context, imagery or extra descriptions. For the realism of the dialogue, I understand that just adding "Do you want breakfast?" or "a.m." can seem out-of-place. However, you could add a description of the character's surroundings. For example, if its 9 o'clock a.m., you could say "she said as the rays of sun gushed into her eyes". This way, you inherently know that it is morning.

Comment: The rays of the sun can "gush" into someone's eyes in the evening as well. I would write "morning sun". (I also wouldn't use "gush", but that may just be me.)

Comment: Yeah, I guess. It just seems like a trait more definitive in the morning. Come to think of it, I like “rush” better. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Questions, expectation, suspense, all of this makes good writing. Even in the tiniest doses. You read it's 9 o'clock and you aren't sure whether it's am or pm and the next line tells you about the girl getting the coffee. And then you find out the coffee's for her late night cramming, You're being pulled along by the story. You won't care whether you originally knew whether it was 9 in the morning or evening!

So:

> *How does the reader know if that's morning or evening?*

I hope I don't! (Not right that second, anyway)